# How to remove lines one by one in Richtextbox C#

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I use this code to delete lines one by one in richtextbox, but still leaving an empty line (whitespace).

```
var text = "";//Holds the text of current line being looped.
var startindex = 0;//The position where selection starts.
var endindex = 0;//The length of selection.

for (int i = 0; i < richtextbox1.Lines.Length; i++)//Loops through each line of text in RichTextBox
{
    text = richtextbox1.Lines[i];  //Stores current line of text.

    startindex = richtextbox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i);
    endindex = text.Length;
    richtextbox1.Select(startindex, endindex);
    MessageBox.Show(richtextbox1.SelectedText);
    richtextbox1.SelectedText = "";              
}
```

How do I delete lines one by one without empty lines (whitespace)?

Comment: Can you give same sample input with sample output? I'm not 100% im sure what you're asking.

Comment: @KSib 

Sample input : 
email1dotcom
email2dotcom
email3dotcom

sample output:
  (space)
  (space)
  (space)

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying now. Nevermind.

Comment: @KSib sorry for typo, I'm hard to explain but see this image http://image.prntscr.com/image/181d939f9dd449dea6615a1c9be02de5.png maybe make you understand

Comment: It's okay. I just loaded your code in Visual Studio and immediately understood what you meant

Answer (score 0):

```
// Gets the number of newline characters in your rich text box
var numberOfNewLines = richTextBox1.Text.Count(r => r == '\n');

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfNewLines; i++)
{
     // Finds the first occurance of the newline character
     var newlineCharacterIndex = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf('\n') + 1;

     // Replaces the rich textbox text with everything but the above line
     richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(newlineCharacterIndex);

     MessageBox.Show("OK!");
}

// Removes the final line.
richTextBox1.Text = string.Empty;
```

I think you were on the right track, but the way you were doing it was just removing the contents of the line and not the line itself.

Comment: this code is working but i just want to delete richtextbox1.SelectedText without whitespace.